# How to find the SearchImpressionShare for a particular keyword?

Tags: google-ads-api

One could easily find the average position for a keyword using `getAveragePositon()` method but the same is not available for SearchImpressionShare.

**EDIT**

I tried to get the SearchImpressionShare by querying the data but that gives me inconsistent data.

```
function main() {

  var keywordId = 297285633818;

  var last14dayStatsQuery = "SELECT Id, SearchTopImpressionShare FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT  WHERE Id = "+keywordId+" DURING LAST_14_DAYS"

  var last14dayReport = AdWordsApp.report(last14dayStatsQuery);

  var last14dayRows = last14dayReport.rows();

  var last14dayRow = last14dayRows.next();

  Logger.log('Keyword: ' + last14dayRow['Id'] + ' SearchTopIS: ' + last14dayRow['SearchTopImpressionShare']);

}
```

For example, below are the two outputs I received after running the same code twice.

Output 1:

`10/16/2019 10:47:29 AM Keyword: 297285633818 SearchTopIS: 0.0`

Output 2:

`10/16/2019 10:47:45 AM Keyword: 297285633818 SearchTopIS: 0.17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords performance report provides you those data https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/keywords-performance-report#searchimpressionshare

sample use:

```
function main () {
  var  query = "SELECT SearchImpressionShare, Criteria FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE Clicks > 15 DURING YESTERDAY"
  var report = AdWordsApp.report(query)
  var rows = report.rows()
  while (rows.hasNext()) {
    var row = rows.next()
    Logger.log('Keyrword %s, Impressions Share %s', row['Criteria'], row['SearchImpressionShare'])
  }
}
```

update:
please note that if you have the same keyword within several ad group you'll get aslo several rows in report, each row for each adgroup. for the whole list of keywords use the following approach:

```
function main() {

  var keywordId = 350608245287;
  var last14dayStatsQuery = "SELECT Id, SearchTopImpressionShare FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT  WHERE Id = "+keywordId+" DURING LAST_14_DAYS"
  var last14dayReport = AdWordsApp.report(last14dayStatsQuery);
  var last14dayRows = last14dayReport.rows();
  while (last14dayRows.hasNext()) {
    var last14dayRow = last14dayRows.next();
    Logger.log('Keyword: ' + last14dayRow['Id'] + ' SearchTopIS: ' + last14dayRow['SearchTopImpressionShare']);
  }
}
```

You might find it useful to add ad group parameters to your query such as `AdGroupName`, `AdGroupId`.

Comment: I was able to query the data, but the results are inconsistent, sometimes the query returns the actual impression share data sometimes it returns 0, is this a timeout issue? Can you try running the same query? I was very surprised that this is happening with a Google Product.

Comment: please keep in mind that 1) report rows are not sorted in the same way for every report request 2) same keywords with different match type has the same ['Criteria'] values. 
And yes, these data are rock-solid.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, so how do you suggest that we get search top impression share for a particular keyword if 'Criteria' is not a unique identifier?

Comment: Each keyword is uniquely identified by its ID and Ad Group ID https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/concepts/ids

Comment: Great, I will use both of them instead of the 'Criteria' field in the same query you had suggested earlier. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I tried to do this on the basis of ID but I am still getting inconsistent data, I have updated the question description with the code and outputs.

Comment: Thank you again! After updating the question I had devised a similar solution as you suggested and that is working.